# php,trazer varias linhas de uma tabela lincada a outra tabela de um unico id

Tags: php, mysqli, if, while

Estou com uma dificuldade em recuperar uma informação.

Nos dados para a impressão, preciso mostrar na variavel `$comp` quando ela pertencer ao mesmo `id_cadastro` que estou consultando, até aqui tudo bem, deu certo, porém eu tenho vario `$comp` para o mesmo `id_cadastro`, a `$comp` é igual a consulta `d_comp` do banco, e em alguns casos eu tenho até 10 `$comp`, estou tentando mostrar quando a (`$comp` for =1 mostrar o `d_comp` 1) referente ao `id_cadastro` da consulta, quando a variável `$volume` for igual a $comp = 1 mostro seu valor.
Dai depois tenho a $comp 2 e sucessivamente.

Já tentei `if`, não da o valor esperado, estou aqui com o `while` mas tbm nao vai.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<?php   require_once("logica_usuario.php");
        verificaUsuario();
        require_once('forms_funcoes.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$imp = impLaudos($conexao, $id);

?>
<body onLoad="javascript:window.print();">
<table width="1411" height="1889" border="0" bordercolorlight="#FC0004" >
  <tbody>


    <tr>
      <td height="29">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5"><?=$imp['cadEquip']?></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="6"><?=$imp['cadInmetro']?></td>
      <td colspan="9"><?=$imp['cadCapaci']?></td>
      <td colspan="6"><?=$imp['cadMarca']?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>

      //daqui para baixo

      <td colspan="2">
          <?php
            //$comp = compartimento
            $comp = $imp['d_comp'];
            $i = 1;
          while($i == $comp){
              echo $comp;
            $i++;
          }

          ?></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <?php

            if($comp == 2){
                echo $comp;

            } else {

                echo "";
            }

        ?>

        </td>
      <td>

          <?php

            if($comp == 3){
                echo $comp;

            } else {

                echo "";
            }

        ?>

        </td>
      <td colspan="3">

          <?php

            if($comp == 4){
                echo $comp;

            } else {

                echo "";
            }

        ?>

        </td>
      <td colspan="2">

        <?php

            if($comp == 5){
                echo $comp;

            } else {

                echo "";
            }

        ?>

        </td>

    </tr>
```

aqui vai a função `impLaudo`:

```
function impLaudos($conexao, $id){
    $query = "select desco.*, 
        cli.cli_nome as nomeCli,
        cli.cli_cnpj as cnpjCli,
        cad.condutor as cadCondutor,
        cad.condutor_cpf as cadCondutor_cpf,
        cad.placa as cadPlaca,
        cad.id_cli,
        cad.data as cadData,
        cad.id as cadId,
        cad.marca_modelo as cadMarcaModelo,
        cad.chassi as cadChassi,
        cad.equipamento as cadEquip,
        cad.num_imetro as cadInmetro,
        cad.capacidade as cadCapaci,
        cad.marca as cadMarca,
        cad.id_fin as cadFinalidade,
        cad.id_proc as cadProcesso
        from descontaminacao as desco
        left join cadastro as cad on cad.id = desco.id_cadastro
        left join cliente as cli on cli.id = cad.id_cli


    where desco.id = {$id}";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

}
```

A tabela **cadastro** é onde fica os dados do cliente e outros, e o id desta tabela fica na tabela **descontaminacao** que por sua vez terá até 10 cadastro para o mesmo id de cadastro, e na impressão deste laudo eu preciso definir para que os dados da `$d_comp` quando for igual a 1, mostre os dados do `d_comp = 1` da tabela descontaminação, do id x da tabela cadastro e quando a `$d_comp` for igual a 2 mostrar os dados do `d_comp` do mesmo id x da tabela cadastro.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho será que consegue me dar um ajuda nesta também?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você quer buscar os dados com o mesmo id da outra tabela, é isso mesmo? Se for você pode usar:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM suatabela WHERE id='idquevocêbusca'")){
    while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo $row['id'];

    }
}
```

É isso mesmo?

Comment: quase isso, mas ja tentei isso e não deu certo, vou tentar posta aqui o codigo para vc entender.

Comment: @JuniorVenancio blz, vou aguardar

Comment: editei minha pergunta @WotonSampaio com o codigo, o que acha?

Comment: Cara, quando eu crio uma tabela que tem por exemplo usuários, e outra que tem seus dados, eu faço na segunda tabela um campo com o nome idcli que recebe o id do cliente, toda vez que o usuário lançar o dado lá, esse idcli recebe seu id da tabela principal, assim na busca eu faço q nem no exemplo que fiz acima, acho que fica mais prático

Comment: Na busca, eu só preciso buscar todos com o idcli correspondente ao id do usuário, entende? Do jeito que você fez você tá comparando todos os campos

Comment: então mas eu estou fazendo assim, da forma como disse a tabela descontaminação carrega o id do cadastro, mas no caso ai eu junto mais tabelas por conta de outras informações que devem ser impressas junto, entende, pois esta descontaminação pode ser feita em vários compartimentos, e na impressão se houver mais de um compartimento descontaminado, tem que ser impresso também, mas cada compartimento tem as suas informações.